# Add Webelement text into list by iterating each element using for loop

Tags: list, selenium, for-loop, arraylist

There are 5 Webelements which share same xpaths. I want to get the text from each element and store it in a list. Below is my failed attempt:

```
List<WebElement> ActualAdFormats_Elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//h4[text()='Select Ad Format']/..//strong)"));
for(WebElement AdFormat:ActualAdFormats_Elements) {
    ActualAdFormat_List.add(AdFormat.getText());
        }
```

Comment: How does it fail? What is the outcome of your code?

Comment: What is the outcome?

Comment: ActualAdFormat_List is null is what i was getting. I was defining it the wrong way. Defined it the way cruise mentioned and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is  `ActualAdFormat_List`  in your code.

Also there's no need to have parenthesis in xpath, remove them as well.

Please define a `list of string` like this :

```
List<String> ActualAdFormat_List = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and use it like this :

```
List<WebElement> ActualAdFormats_Elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h4[text()='Select Ad Format']/..//strong"));
for(WebElement AdFormat : ActualAdFormats_Elements) {
    ActualAdFormat_List.add(AdFormat.getText());
        }
```

Make sure that,

```
//h4[text()='Select Ad Format']/..//strong
```

represent all 5 web elements in `HTMLDOM`.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: I was defining List of string the wrong way hence it was null. Defined it the way you mentioned. Works now. Thanks.